# Custom iPhone camera controls (not using UIImagePickerController)

Tags: ios, camera

While I understand that in order for an iPhone application to be accepted on the App Store, one requirement is that only documented libraries are to be used.

If this is the case, how are certain applications such as "Night Camera" and "Camera Plus" using a camera control that seems to be something other than the one contained within UIImagePickerController?

I have heard of certain cases where a developer has been given "special" access to certain headers that allow for features that would otherwise be impossible if constrained to only using documented libraries.  However, given how opaque the application selection process is for the App Store, I would prefer to stick to what is recommended rather than take my chances.

Anyone care to shed some more light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to check out a classdump of apple's private framework headers.  Run this perl script:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2008/11/dumping-the-iphone-2-2-frameworks.ars

and navigate to the PhotoLibrary directory under PrivateFrameworks.  Some of the classes in here look pretty promising for direct camera access.

Using the undocumented API could hurt your chances of passing through the app store, but it's all very subjective - If your product is good, apple will probably let it slide through.  I'd recommend making friends with a developer evangelist at Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the framework dump link.  I'll run the script for educational purposes but will stick with the documented classes for now.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you come up with a solution that doesn't violate apple's terms

Answer (score 8):

Have you seen this dicussion?

http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/11/views-of-uiimagepickercontroller/

and this sample code for a custom picker?

http://www.codza.com/custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-view

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The UIImagePickerController is a UIViewController subclass that manages a view hierarchy. You are free to play around with the view hierarchy, as those apps are, but it is risky considering that Apple does not document it and could change it on any OS update.

I have not heard of anyone being given special access to libraries, but I have read that there is a minor distinction between undocumented classes and methods and private frameworks. Undocumented classes are a gray area, but private frameworks are definitely not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple explanation is that apps in the store are not supposed to use unsupported APIs, but this is not checked consistently.  The apps you mentioned are either using unsupported functions/classes/methods or else are playing with the view hierarchy-- which is itself undocumented even though it can be done with standard APIs.

You could do what they do, and take your chances with it.  Just be aware of the risks.  Your app might (a) be rejected from the store, (b) be accepted but later booted (this has happened for unsupported API use), (c) be accepted and not booted but break the next time Apple has a new iPhone software update (since unsupported APIs or view hierarchies can change without warning).  Or you could get lucky and have none of this happen.