# How do I access the iPhone camera API without the camera interface?

Tags: iphone

How can I take a picture in my iPhone app without going through the camera interface?

I've read things about CameraController. Is that what I should look into, or is there an easier way to just snap a picture with code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561868/custom-iphone-camera-controls-not-using-uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant access the camera without the iphone API, however what they have allowed is for you to provide your custom view to be used on top of the camera interface, what you have to do is set the cameraOverlayView property of a UIImagePIckerController, [here is the reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView), as the solution posted in the comment points out, you might be able to access the camera, but through private frameworks which could hurt your chances of approval to the appstore