# In need of basics of AVFoundation to capture images from device camera

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, avfoundation, cclayer, isight

I want to know that how can we capture image using AVFoundation framework, I have managed to activate the camera and my Cocos2D view is over the camera and is tranparent. I have tried using some tutorials but I am unable to capture the images( Still Image). I do not want to capture the images of a video, I want a normal camera functionality of clicking the images and then saving them to the camera roll.

I am trying this since two days and I am really stuck at this, when I press the capture button the only thing I get in camera roll is blank white screen.

Please suggest me any tutorial that would cover the basics of how to use AVFoundation framework or any help will be really appreciated. :)

Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: You can not access the camera image without using [UIPickerViewController][2]. At least [not with the official API][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561868/custom-iphone-camera-controls-not-using-uiimagepickercontroller
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113/access-the-camera-with-iphone-sdk

Comment: Actually, what i need is to capture photo with the CCLayer on it. Therefore I was thinking of a way to capture the entire iPhone screen, Like 'getScreenImage'. After some searching I learned that AVFoundation is the Apple replacement for 'getSCreenImage'.. ?